# Serial.println printing just after the previous string in same line

Tags: serial, programming

I wrote serial.println in my code but the string was printed in same line on serial moniter.

```
#include <WiFi.h>//for connecting esp32 to a wifi

#include <TinyGPS++.h>//to obtain gps data from neo-6m gps module 

#define WIFI_SSID "Airtel_pawa_4182"//wifi name in simple words
#define WIFI_PWD "Ahuja6230"//wifi password

TinyGPSPlus GPS;//creating a gps object from tinygps++ library

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
  //wifi setup{
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PWD);
  Serial.println("connecting to wifi");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
   Serial.println(".");
   delay(1000);    
  }
  Serial.println("Successfully connected to ");
  Serial.print(WIFI_SSID);
  //}

  //gps setup{
  Serial2.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("ESP32-GPS Tracker");
  Serial.println("Initializing...");
  //}
}

void loop() {
}
```

In this code the string "esp32-gps tracker" is printing just after the previous string in same line on serial moniter.

I tried running code again and again but it didn't work...

I am using esp32 board(just a detail)

What do i do?

Comment: You need to be _way_ more specific for your question to be answerable. Same line? Same as what? Please, post a minimal testable sketch showing the issue, tell us what you expected as an output, and tell us what the actual output was.

Comment: @EdgarBonet done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous print statements are these:

```
  Serial.println("Successfully connected to ");
  Serial.print(WIFI_SSID);
```

The SSID won't be terminated by a newline. Perhaps you meant:

```
  Serial.print("Successfully connected to ");
  Serial.println(WIFI_SSID);
```

?

Answer (score 1):

To follow on from previous answer, your solution is to either:

- change the previous Serial.print() to a Serial.println() so that that text is followed by a line end, or
- add a \n to the front of the line you are having the problem with, so it starts with a new line, to make up for the "missing" new line in the previous Serial.print().

Comment: For consistency with what `Serial.println()` does, you should add `"\r\n"`, not only `'\n'`. If you ever use a terminal emulator instead of the Arduino serial monitor, a bare `'\n'` will likely move the cursor one line down while staying on the same column.

Comment: Depends on your operating system. In Linux a newline advances to the start of a new line. On Windows YMMV. It's very common in Linux code to use \n for a newline when outputting and not \r\n, which may in fact put some weird character (the carriage-return character) in your terminal window.

Comment: @NickGammon: On a Linux terminal, a `\n` alone is a vertical-only cursor movement. When a program outputs `\n`, the tty driver converts it to `\r\n` before it reaches the terminal. This should become clear if you try to use a terminal with this output post-processing disabled (`stty -opost`). A serial communication program like picocom, by default, disables all tty driver processing: the bytes from the Arduino reach the terminal unaltered. This plays well with `Serial.println()`, as it ends the line with `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

When sending text through a serial line, it is customary to
**terminate** each line with some sort of end-of-line marker: you print
some text, and immediately *after* it the EOL to signify that “this is
now a complete line”. Accordingly, the `Serial.println()` method prints
the requested text, immediately *followed* by the EOL marker (in this
case, CR+LF).

From your question, you seem to be thinking that the EOL immediately
*precedes* the text. This is not the case.

See JRobert's answer for the correct way to build a line from multiple
print statements: `println()` should be use on the last piece, not on
the first one.

Comment: Yes. Nice explanation. Now I know where I mistook. I thought that by using "print.ln()", the string will be printed in new line(I got this info from google). But it isn't like that print.ln is for terminating a line and starting a new line

Comment: Jrobert's comment was the first one to mark my mistake so I declared it as answer. But I also thank you for the explanation

Comment: @YugAhuja `println` not `print.ln` you need to be very specific when coding.